# opening window animation like Microsoft security essentials

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm working on a project where I need to display notification popups.

http://youtu.be/fweLIzpW6I0?t=52s

Here you see the way I want the notification to display. Microsoft Security Essentials uses a popup-window which grows. I can't find a way to do it like that.

This is the window:

```
<Window x:Class="AlertDialog"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Notification"
Height="196" Width="400"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
ShowInTaskbar="False"
Topmost="True"
HorizontalAlignment="Right"
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">

<Grid Name="contentGrid">

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You can look into WPF animations. And then animate on positions and opacity.

Comment: yes, but the position of the window changes on diferent screen sizes